# How do I get the log group name and ARN of a lambda generated by CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm generating a lambda in CloudFormation like this:

```
TestFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: lib/test.handler
    Timeout: 30
    Role: !GetAtt ExecutionRole.Arn
```

Now, CloudFormation will automatically create me a log group for this lambda. How do I access that log groups name and ARN?

I do NOT want to create a log group and then associate it to my lambda. I want to access the log group that is created for me automatically.

Comment: The CloudFormation does not create the log group. When Lambda runs and if the role attached to Lambda has permission to create log group, a log group is created then only. The ARN of the log group will look like this: `arn:${Partition}:logs:${Region}:${Account}:log-group:${Lambda_Function_Name}`.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/147

Answer (score 7):

Log group created by a lambda function will have a name of the form `/aws/lambda/<function name>`. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html

You can construct the name of the log group with:

```
!Sub '/aws/lambda/${TestFunction}'
```

and the arn:

```
!Sub 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/${TestFunction}:*'
```

Comment: Note: log group isn't created until first invocation, so you may get resource not found errors. Not sure what the alternative is.